# Python @property Mapper 'mapped class User->user' has no property 'member_groups

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Context: For my work, I'm running a script `populate.py` where we populate a database. It fails at a certain advanced stage (let's just say step 9) as I'm trying to add a new many to many association table.

I made some changes to correspond to a similar entity that works. Specifically I added some `@property` and `@x.setter` methods because I thought that would solve it or at least be good practice. Now I get a failure at an earlier stage that was working before (let's say step 4).

I'm not looking for a solution to either of these issues but an understanding of how there could be such an error as logged with respect to how python is designed to work.

The error is:

```
`sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Mapper 'mapped class User->user' has no property 'member_groups'`
```

I did change a class attribute from

```
member_groups
```

to

```
_member_groups
```

But I also added the following code

```
@property
def member_groups(self) -> List[MemberGroup]:
    return self._member_groups

@member_groups.setter
def member_groups(self, new_member_groups): 
    '''
    Now, what do we do with you? 
    '''
    self._member_groups = new_member_groups
```

I thought the whole point of the `@property` decorator in python was for this very use case- that I could call the class attribute `_foobar` as long as I had the decorator grabbing and setting it correctly..

```
@property
def member_groups(self):
    return self._foobar
```

..and that it shouldn't make any difference what the class attribute is called as long as we give what we want the user to access it through the property descriptor. I thought that was the whole purpose or at least a major point of this pythonic api, specifically to create pseudo private variables and not have it make a difference or be breaking with existing code, but it shows that `mapped class has no property`.

I just want the theory, not a code solution per se, although I'll take ideas if you have them. I just want to understand Python better.

Comment: In this case, `property` is referring to a column on a table.  The mapper is trying to map a relationship between `User` and some other table, and the relationship  references `member_groups`, probably through `back_populates`, but the `User` model does not have a column named `member_groups`.  What you are trying to do works in plain Python, but not in the specific case of SQLAlchemy's mapper machinery.

Comment: It's the mapper machinery that confuses me and the fact that the error was a plain python error and not a SQLAlchemy error, leading me to think I don't understand how property works.